# Problems installing Compass 960 Plugin

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sass, compass-sass

I am trying to install the gem [compass 960 plugin](https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass-960-plugin)

I did

```
D:\Websites\css3-mega-menu>gem install compass-960-plugin
Successfully installed compass-960-plugin-0.10.0
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for compass-960-plugin-0.10.0...
Installing RDoc documentation for compass-960-plugin-0.10.0...
```

Seems ok. But ...

```
D:\Websites\css3-mega-menu>compass frameworks
Available Frameworks & Patterns:

  * blueprint
    - blueprint/basic       - A basic blueprint install that mimics the actual blueprint css.
    - blueprint/buttons     - Button Plugin
    - blueprint/link_icons  - Icons for common types of links
    - blueprint/project     - The blueprint framework.
    - blueprint/semantic    - The blueprint framework for use with semantic markup.
  * compass
    - compass/ellipsis      - Plugin for cross-browser ellipsis truncated text.
    - compass/extension     - Generate a compass extension.
    - compass/project       - The default project layout.
  * fancy-buttons
    - fancy-buttons/project
```

But compass don't seem to detect it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try editing your `config.rb` file and adding `require "960gs"` at the top. I can't be sure of the value itself (i.e. it might simply be `require "960"`), but I had to apply the require with Susy as:

```
require "susy"
```

I asked a [similar question](http://groups.google.com/group/compass-users/browse_thread/thread/23c1d4c83017ea5a/c5c429539eea8aa3?lnk=gst&q=wilkerson#c5c429539eea8aa3) in the Compass Google Group.

Answer (score 0):

I've just come across this question after getting the same problem. Like Rob Wilkerson said you need to require the correct plugin.

```
# Require any additional compass plugins here.
require "ninesixty" 
# Set this to the root of your project when deployed:
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "stylesheets"
sass_dir = "src"
images_dir = "images"
javascripts_dir = "javascripts"
# To enable relative paths to assets via compass helper functions. Uncomment:
# relative_assets = true
```